# How would I show that a function is one-to-one using symbols?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

If I have a function $f: X\to Y$ and its inverse $f^{-1}: Y\to X$, how would I show that it is one-to-one using symbols?

I can not figure out if it would be correct for me to say $\forall\ y\in f^{-1}\ \exists!\ x$. We know that it is one-to-one, so there is only one x per y value. I am just not sure if this is correct.

Comment: What do you have against using words?

Comment: Nothing at all, I am just required to complete the statement ∀y∈____, and I am unsure of exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Injectivity of function $f:A\rightarrow B$ means that

$\forall a,a'\in A: f(a)=f(a')\Rightarrow a=a'$.